# C++ Class Method Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, methods, constants, static-variables

I have recently transitioned from Java to C++, and I am having some difficulties working out how class inheritance works exactly. Currently, I have the class `Weapon` and the class `Minigun`. `Minigun` inherits the class `Weapon`, which means it should have the methods and variables that `Weapon` defines. My issue is that I have a private constant static int inside `Weapon` called `rate`, and a public method that returns an integer called `getRate()`. `getRate()` simply returns the rate variable as defined in the class. When `Minigun` extends `Weapon`, and I set the rate inside `Minigun`, the `getRate()` method still returns the constant from the `Weapon` class, even though it is being called on the `Minigun` class. I thought it would act like Java, and the intherited method would use the modified variable inside `Minigun`. Currently I have to do the following;

**Weapon.h**

```
#ifndef __WEAPON__
#define __WEAPON__

class Weapon
{
    public:
        virtual int getRate()
        {
            return rate;
        }
    private:
        const static int rate = 0;
};

#endif
```

**Minigun.h**

```
#include "Weapon.h"

#ifndef __WEAPON_MINIGUN__
#define __WEAPON_MINIGUN__

class Minigun: public Weapon
{
public:
    int getRate(); // I have to define this here, and create it inside Minigun.cpp
private:
    const static int rate = 30;
};

#endif
```

**Minigun.cpp**

```
#include "Minigun.h"

int Minigun::getRate() // Is there a way so I do not need to type this out for every class that extends Weapon?
{
    return rate;
}
```

Comment: try `return Minigun::rate;` in minigun .cpp.  No gaurentee

Comment: @Chemistpp My Minigun.cpp works fine, I am looking to completely remove the getRate() function from Minigun.cpp, and use the one already defined in Weapon

Comment: remove rate from class minigun and the getrate function.  When you call those functions on minigun, they will just call the inherited functions.

Comment: When I remove that, the getRate() inside Weapon is called (which is what I want), but it returns the "rate" constant from inside the base Weapon class, instead of the one inside Minigun.

Comment: I'm not sure if overloading works for static class member variables or not, but why not just use a function that returns the value directly (e.g. `return 30;`) if it's const anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have it be static.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Weapon {
    public:
       Weapon();
       virtual int Rate();
       virtual void Rate(int r);
    protected:
       int rate;
};

Weapon::Weapon() {
    rate = 10;
}

class Minigun : public Weapon {
    public: 
         Minigun();
};

Minigun::Minigun() {
    rate = 30;
}

int Weapon::Rate() {
    return rate;
}
void Weapon::Rate(int r) {
    rate = r;
}

int main() {
    Minigun ThisGun;
    Weapon AnyGun;
    std::cout << ThisGun.Rate() << std::endl;
    std::cout << AnyGun.Rate() << std::endl;
    AnyGun.Rate(15);
    std::cout << AnyGun.Rate() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

We declare a protected int in the base class.  This means any derived class that inherits the base class will have that variable as well.  You only declare a variable `static` if you want only one instance of that variable shared for all instances of that object.

Base constructors will get called before the derived constructor.  You can reset default values in your derived constructor for objects of that specific type.  Public functions will call the most derived virtual function.  In this case, we want `Minigun` to behave the same for our rate functions so we simple do not implement any function for `Minigun` so the `Weapon` functions are called instead.
output is:

```
30
10
15
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid setting the variable in the constructor (I don't remember why, something about keeping variables separate). However, this seems to be the best way to achieve exactly what I want. Thanks :)

Comment: There still seems to be an issue with my version. When having the constructor `Minigun::Minigun() { rate = 30 }` inside the Minigun.cpp, I get an error stating that `Weapon::rate` is private. What can I do about this other than using a setter/getter combo?

Comment: `protected:` make sure it's declared as

Comment: if you really need rate private, create a protected (or public) setter.

Answer (score 2):

`Weapon` instances would return a rate of `Weapon::rate` through `getRate()` and `Minigun` instances would return a rate of `Minigun::rate`.

Because the method `getRate()` is virtual a `Weapon` pointer or reference to a `Minigun` instance would return a rate of `Minigun::rate`.

If only the rate variable changes in the derived classes, a template class would require less coding than the dynamic polymorphic version. The template version would look like:

```
    template<int Rate = 0>
    class Weapon
    {
        public:
            int getRate() // no need for virtual anymore
            {
                return rate;
            }
        private:
            const static int rate = Rate;
    };

    class Minigun: public Weapon<30> {};
```